# Why Divs appear between other divs if Float is set?

Tags: html, css

I need to set a layout for 4 sections, similar to a table, but using only divs and CSS. This is the desired output:

```
Logo-----------Info
Business-------Client
```

I though it would be as easy as set `Float` property, but if I set that property to left and right for the `Logo` and `Info`, then the `Business` and `Client` divs appear between them instead of beneath them instead of the desired result.

```
Logo----Business----Client---Info
```

Code at: http://jsfiddle.net/YMh3C/304/

I'd like the code fixed, but more than anything I want to understand why this behaviour happens.

```css
#logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#info {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}

#business {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#client {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="logo">
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="business">
    <div>{{ temp_business1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business3 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business4 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business5 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_numerodefactura }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_fechadefactura }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="client">
    <div>{{ temp_client1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client3 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client4 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client5 }}</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `float` then you must need to put `clear: both;` property to keep the upcoming section in new line.

For more info you can refer https://css-tricks.com/all-about-floats/

And for now you can put a blank div with `clear: both;` after `#info`

Comment: I'll accept this answero for the link to the explanation, which is what I need most then just the fix. Other answers focus more on "do this" but don't explain it as well. I understand how it works now thanks to you.

Answer (score 3):

Just Add one div with `clear:both` after `info` div or add `clear:both` css in `#business`

```css
#logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}

#info {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;      
}

#business {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  clear:both;
}

#client {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
}
.clear {
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="logo">
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <div id="business">
    <div>{{ temp_business1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business3 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business4 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business5 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_numerodefactura }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_fechadefactura }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="client">
    <div>{{ temp_client1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client3 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client4 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client5 }}</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

From your current css, the easiest way is to add `clear: left;` onto `#business`

This will force the next float to move underneath the previous left. Also moving the client div down too.

```
#business {
  clear: left
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
}
```

After this, you can then play about with padding/margins to give you the end result.

Comment: Hm, yup, this seems to work fine. I wonder what difference will make clear: left from clear:both. Could you explain?

Answer (score 0):

here is what all you need, try avoiding float and do it with table cell

```css
section{
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
section > div{
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="logo">
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="business">
    <div>{{ temp_business1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business3 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business4 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business5 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_numerodefactura }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_fechadefactura }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="client">
    <div>{{ temp_client1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client3 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client4 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client5 }}</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Hm, not really. That puts everything on the same line, while I need the last 2 divs under the first 2 ones.

Answer (score 0):

To get the desired output, you can simply give a fixed width to your main divs and float them all left. I have given 50% width.

```css
#logo {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width:50%;
}

#info {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width:50%;
}

#business {
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  width:50%;
}

#client {
  float: right;
  text-align: center;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div id="logo">
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
    <div>{{ Logo }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="info">
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
    <div>{{ Info }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="business">
    <div>{{ temp_business1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business3 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business4 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_business5 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_numerodefactura }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_fechadefactura }}</div>
  </div>
  <div id="client">
    <div>{{ temp_client1 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client2 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client3 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client4 }}</div>
    <div>{{ temp_client5 }}</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand why it happens we should look on how float actually works.
Imagine that you have a box with "left" polar magnet on the left and "right" polar magnet on the right. Also the top of the box is pulling all the blocks up. So when you drop a "left" element into an empty box it goes directly to the top-left corner, then you drop a "right" element and it goes directly to the right upper corner. And if you drop another "left" element small enough to fit between those previous two the last one stick exactly there. Because float element tends to float to a border or *another element*.

More scientific explanation can be found at [Float specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float)